# Help with finding an objective function for optimization

Tags: optimization

Im working in comsol and needed help figuring out the objective function for the following situation (Comsol does have multiple objective function option as min max or sum of)
I have 7 batteries connected in parallel all at the same voltage discharging. I need the current from each as uniform as possible with the maximum (the battery closest to the tab) also being as small as possible. Currently i used the standard deviation and the max of the 7 batteries as objectives and used the sum. What do you suggest?
[image]
[image]

Comment: It is not clear to me what your intention is. What are you trying to optimize for and what are your design variables?

Comment: @nicoguaro So im trying to minimize battery degradation, increase pack power and capacity by assuring that the current from each battery is about equal to each other. This allows for each cell to not overshoot safety limits etc etc. Im only considering the busbar geometry so the radius, the distance between batteries, the thickness, placement of outlet hole and the rotation of the rectangular outlet tab. Yes most of these dont really require optiimization but still id like to know

Comment: Can you write down your problem mathematically? For example, what is the objective function?